# MSSQL database lock stopping my application?

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm having an issue in my java application where once I login I'm able to access any pages that dont' query a table called `content`.  When I try to query this table it sits and sits and sits waiting for something.  I checked the Activity Monitor in MsSQL and it appears there's a lock.  I'm trying to figure out where this came from.  I'm newer to MsSQL with a background in MySQL.

I thought some queries in our DAO might be causing this, so I changed them to use JPA instead with no luck.

[image: MsSQL Activity Montior]

Comment: you want to free the locks on the table or find the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table? Post the code you are using to access the table.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm hoping to find the cause of the problem

Comment: @Perception - No, there aren't.  The query being run is generated by Java's JPA which despite query logging appears to not be caught by the Glassfish log.  All of my other queries are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like session 58 is blocked by session 74.  Check if session 74 is blocked by another session, and so on, until you find the root lock.

You can kill a session by right clicking it, or by executing a query like:

```
kill 74
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem has been addressed above, but the more general problem is that your code does not configure the jdbc driver timeouts for query execution.  It's very driver specific on how to do this, so you'll have to do the research for sqlserver to figure out how.

Typically it's just a matter of setting some properties on whatever is managing your connections.  Typically this would be on the underlying javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: Can you explain how you know this is a timeout issue?  I'm concerned about the potential affects timeout might have on our application...

Comment: According to our Connection Pool setting the timeout is set for 300 seconds